# Pycharm Debugger "ImportError: cannot import name copy"

Tags: debugging, pycharm

When I try to debug, it gives the following error:
Connection to Python debugger failed
Interrupted function call: accept failed

However, I can still Run the script. I just upgraded to Pycharm 2020 from 2018 and the error still persists...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved: The problem was I had a copy.py file in the same directory.